# Where and what i am doing wrong in my JS Code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck why this code is not working. Why Image position not fixed when i scroll down the window.

I know this is a very common question help would be appreciated.

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if($(window).scrollTop() === 200){
     $("#dataImg").css({'position':'fixed','top':'0px'});
    }
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 1500px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x300" id="dataImg">
</div>
```

Comment: Question updated

Comment: `scrollTop()` will never exactly hit `200`; start by changing `===` to `>`

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is with the "$(window).scrollTop === 200". You want to use > or < depending on your situation like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if($(window).scrollTop() > 200){
    $("#dataImg").css({'position':'fixed','top':'0px'});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to fix that image when you scroll down over 200px.
You can change your Javascript code to following:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= 200){
      $("#dataImg").css({'position':'fixed','top':'0px'});
    } else {
      $("#dataImg").css({'position': '', 'top' : ''});
    }
});
```